# d3 events issue with angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to include zooming and panning functionality in d3. which works in javascript but giving error in typescript.
d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale are not working in angular2 typescript

```
this.svg = this.host.append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .style({ 'float': 'right' })
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
        .append('svg:g');

        function redraw() {
        this.svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
            + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

show this error on console.

```
   Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'. Property 'scale' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
```

Comment: Does using `(<any>d3.event).translate` and `(<any>d3.event).scale` work? (not suggesting you should use them like that)

Comment: Is it a transpilation error or when you run the script? If the second, check your d3 version.

Comment: not giving previous error but giving a new one 
Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

Comment: Dear mkaran thank u so much it works. second error was because of mine code . kindly can you post it as a answer so that others can take benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mkaran's answer works, but rather defeats the purpose of typescript.  The proper cast here is:

```
function redraw() {

  let e = (<d3.ZoomEvent> d3.event);

  this.svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + e.translate + ")"
    + " scale(" + e.scale + ")");
}
```

Since the purpose the TypeScript is *types*, resorting to `any` is considered bad practice*.

You should also attempt to avoid in-line functions, and rather use proper methods of your class.  But that's a question for another day...

<sub>*sometimes it's just easier :)</sub>

Comment: +1 `<any>` was just suggested as a troubleshooting step :) it should never be used as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with your scope of `this`

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
        .append('svg:g');

        function redraw() {
        this.svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
            + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

should be something like:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw.bind(this))) //<-- bind the outer this here
        .append('svg:g');

        function redraw() {
        this.svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
            + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

or with the es6 arrow syntax:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", ()=> redraw() ) ) //<-- arrow syntax
        .append('svg:g');

        function redraw() {
        this.svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
            + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```